# Can a Map in Dart contains functions?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried to make a Map that contains functions. And when I tried to run it, it returned error :

> The method "mltply" isn't defined for the type Map.

```
Map<String, Function> library = {
    "mltply": (int x, int y) => x * y,
    "addtn": (int x, int y) => x + y
  };
  print(library.mltply(2, 4));
```

Comment: You would need to do `library['mltply']!(2, 4)` or `library['mltply']?.call(2, 4)`.  Dart isn't like JavaScript where classes and associative arrays are equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Your code is wrong, try this:

```
Map<String, Function> library = {
    "mltply": (int x, int y) => x * y,
    "addtn": (int x, int y) => x + y
  };
  print(library["mltply"]!(2, 4));
```

Notice, maps need to be accessed via brackets and a string (unlike Javascript).

Furthermore, you should give your functions explicit function definitions when possible.

Instead of `Function` use `int Function(int, int)`